# Обновление изображения на странице при изменении содержимого файла с изображением

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, websocket, django-rest-framework

Задача: 
Нужно организовать обновление изображений на странице, если файлы с этими изображениями на сервере изменились. Можно все сразу, если хотя бы один изменился, можно только те, что изменились. Именно чтобы пользователь сразу видел на странице, что, например, изображение в файле img1.jpg выглядит теперь иначе. Содержимое файлов на сервере может меняться раз в минуту или реже. 
Делать это нужно без перезагрузки страницы, а время просмотра страницы пользователем может быть несколько суток, неделя и т.д. Клиентов может быть одновременно несколько, и у всех должно происходить обновление.

На сервере `Django` + `Django REST`. 
На странице при помощи AngularJS  выводятся изображения `<img ng-src="" src="" ...>`. Их адреса получаются посредством запроса `$http.get` к `Django REST API`.
 Нашел такие идеи:

- `web-socket` с `Tornado`, но, во-первых, не получилось разобраться в этой связке, во-вторых, есть ли смысл держать соединение только для обновления картинок на одной странице? И тогда, получается, будет два backend-a - один `REST` для `http` запросов, другой - для сокета (причем ориентировочно только для одной страницы). 
  Если я правильно понимаю, в javascript есть поддержка web-сокетов?
  Предположим, каким-то образом (остается вопрос, каким?) я буду отслеживать изменение хэш-суммы или даты изменения каждого файла, или даже всей директории с файлами, и каким-то образом сообщать по сокету о том, что нужно перезагрузить картинки. Как это реализовать?
- ajax и дергать запрос, например, каждую минуту
- по таймеру в контроллере или в отдельном независимом `javascript` дописывать новый рандомный параметр к `src` изображения, например, `src="/img1.jpg?timestamp=12345"` - по идее тогда при изменении `src` изображение будет переподгружаться без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: `один REST для http запросов, другой - для сокета` Всё верно. Получится микросервисная архитектура. Так и должно быть.
`отслеживать изменение хэш-суммы...` Всё просто. Кто-то изменил изображение. Изображение сохраняется на диск, мета-данные уходят в базу и отправляется по websocket протоколу широковещательный ответ (broadcast) об изменении всем слушателям.  Можно между `уходят в базу и отправляется по websocket ` задействовать лёгкого посредника в лице сервиса MQ. Таким образом, вам не нужно всё время дёргать БД и спрашивать об изменениях в ней.

Comment: `ajax и дергать запрос, например, каждую минуту ` Это называется polling.

Answer (score 1):

поскольку я нашел этот вопрос, когда у самого появилась похожая задача, несмотря на давность его и не актуальность у автора, все же напишу, что при возникновении такой задачи у меня, я сделал по третьему Варианту, описанному Вами. по событию менял параметр получаемый функцией `Math.random()` и картинки обновлялись. выглядело это так:

```
`src="/img1.jpg?0.23659"`
```